# How to inject service into middleware using NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I've a middleware to validate a user `quota` and I need to inject the service that call the database into it to check this quota.

This is the middleware:

```js
export class PointMaxStorageMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

    constructor(private readonly points: PointsService) {}

    async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const total = await this.points.count('user-id-test');
        if (total >= LIMIT) throw new HttpException('error sample', 400);
        // ...
    }
}
```

The service class:

```js
@Injectable()
export class PointsService {
    private readonly logger = new Logger(PointsService.name);

    constructor(
        @InjectModel(Point.name)
        private readonly collection: Model<PointDocument>,
    ) {}

    async count(userId: string): Promise<number> {
        return await this.collection.countDocuments({ userId: userId });
    }
}
```

My service class has the `Injectable` annotation and is being used on other parts of the project, but when I inject it into the middleware, I got the error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count')

**The `count` method exist on the service.**

I also tried to use like this:

```js
constructor(
    @Inject(PointsService) private readonly points: PointsService,
) {}
```

And got the erro:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PointsService (?). Please make sure that the argument PointModel at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.
> Potential solutions:
>
> - If PointModel is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
> - If PointModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that > module imported within AppModule? @Module({ imports: [ /* the Module containing PointModel */ ]})
>   Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PointsService (?). Please make sure that the argument PointModel at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Also tried to add a new provider on the `AppModule` class:

```js
providers: [
    {
        provide: 'POINT_SERVICE',
        useClass: PointsService,
    },
]
```

```js
constructor(
    @Inject('POINT_SERVICE') private readonly points: PointsService,
) {}
```

And got the same error as above.

The injection is not being placed correctly, how can I inject a service into a middleware?

Answer (score 2):

You should have the `@Injectable()` on classes that you want inject things into.

Since you want to inject `PointsService` in the class `PointMaxStorageMiddleware`, you need to annotate `PointMaxStorageMiddleware` with that decorator.

Another approach would be:
`@Inject(PointsService) private readonly points: PointsService`

Comment: I tried to use the `@Inject(PointsService)` but this error appears: `Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the class PointMaxStorageMiddleware`

Answer (score 1):

Nest cant resolve dependencies for an injectable that are outside its parent module

Remember `NestMiddleware` is also an `@injectable()`. This means first you define it, and then you must set it up using the `configure()` method in a module (as the `@module` decorator has no place for middleware) like so:

```
@Module({
  providers: [PointsService],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(PointMaxStorageMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('myroute');
  }
}
```

note that `PointsService` should be in the same module, be that through `providers` or through `imports` (if exported from another module)

check https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware for more information

Comment: When I use `PointsService` on provider key I got the error saying that nest can't resolve the dependency of the service; `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PointsService (?). Please make sure that the argument PointModel at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.`

Comment: could you include in the question the code of the PointsService? bear in mind that if PointsService injects dependencies, these too must be imported in the module

Comment: `PointsService` also have a dependency injection of a `mongo` Model, I'm gonna write it on the question

Comment: how are you importing PointModel into the module where PointsService is?

Comment: I'm not importing the "PointModel" on point module because in order to generate the "Model" I have to declare `Model<PointDocument>`, do I need to import into `providers`?

Comment: I've added the `Model<PointDocument>` on the app module providers and got this error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tree')`

Comment: It is still not clear where exactly are you applying the middleware. adding module definitions would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

As `Manuel Herrera` answer mentioned before that you must set the middleware up using the `configure()`. But, remember that in NestJS if you want to share providers across the module, you have to import the source / the hosting module, not just provide the specified provider you want to use. In this case, if you want to share or provide the PointsService at the middleware module. It would be something like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [PointsModule], // this is the module where you provide the PointsService
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(PointMaxStorageMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('myroute');
  }
}
```

You can take a look at the dependency injection section inside the NestJS middleware documentation [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#dependency-injection).